Why can't my launchdaemon find the bash commands?
I'm writing a bash script that enables and disables sleeping on my MacBook based on whether my headphones are connected by bluetooth or not, so I can close the lid and listen to music without the distraction. It is triggered every 5 seconds by a LaunchDaemon task. It uses the blueutil command here and I have it run this script in my Users/username/Library/Scripts folder:
#!/usr/bin/env

export PATH=$(cat /Users/klumpy/Library/Scripts/PATH)

export BLUEUTIL_ALLOW_ROOT=1

# Check if "WF-1000XM3 is connected, if yes disable sleep, if not, don't go to sleep.

echo $(blueutil --connected)
echo $(blueutil --connected | grep "WF-1000XM3")

if [[ $(blueutil --connected | grep "WF-1000XM3" -c) -ne 0 ]]; then

  sudo pmset disablesleep 1
  echo "Sleep Disabled"

else

  sudo pmset disablesleep 0
  echo "Sleep Enabled"

fi

My plist file is here:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
      <string>com.example.bluetoothsleep</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>sudo</string>
      <string>bash</string>
      <string>/Users/klumpy/Library/Scripts/disablesleep</string>
    </array>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
      <string>/Users/klumpy/Documents/Programming/bin/stderr.txt</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
      <string>/Users/klumpy/Documents/Programming/bin/stdout.txt</string>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
      <integer>5</integer>
  </dict>
</plist>

The problem is, it can't find the installed commands. blueutil was installed via brew, and I can run it in a terminal window, or if I run the disablesleep file from terminal and it runs fine. At first, it couldn't find the commands, so I had it print $PATH to my stout.txt file, and I got this:
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
Which obviously is not everything. So I opened a new terminal and copied $PATH to a PATH file in the same directory as my script, and I have the program export the path in line 3. I have confirmed that $PATH now includes the path to the script and all the other directories you get when running echo $PATH in a normal terminal window. Now I get this output from the program above:


Sleep Enabled

So the first two lines of echo don't do anything.
Normally, the blueutil --connected outputs the following when headphones are conneted, and nothing when they are not:
address: 94-db-56-96-b6-e0, connected (master, 0 dBm), not favourite, paired, name: "WF-1000XM3", recent access date: 2024-11-08 19:28:33 +0000
So what am I doing wrong? How do I fix this? Is my bash syntax wrong, and it's not actually running blueutil?

The simplest solution is to use the full path to the blueutil program.

Shellcheck identifies several problems with the code.  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run Shellcheck on all new and modified shell code.

echo $(command) is almost never needed, it's essentially the same as just running command.

What's in /Users/klumpy/Library/Scripts/PATH?

You said you copied your $PATH to PATH.txt. But you're reading PATH, not PATH.txt in the script. They're not the same thing (don't be fooled by FInder hiding extensions).

Thank you @Barmar. Sorry, The file is called PATH, I have extensions to always show by default in finder to minimize confusion, (but still it finds a way... lol) It still doesn't work even when referencing the file directly by path, and I have confirmed that it exported $PATH correctly, and the /opt/homebrew/bin/ path where the file is, is there.

Is it possible that blueutil does not run from this context?

I tried running one of my python files with the python3 command, and I get (...) can't open file '<path/to/file>': [Errno 1] Operation not permitted, even if I run it with sudo The file is in my home directory and I can normally run it from the terminal.

In your Terminal, run the command type blueutil and it will tell you the full path to your blueutil command.

So, it turns out, none of my paths were wrong. The daemon could find the script just fine; the blueutil command for some reason doesn't interface with the bluetooth module correctly when run from this context. I put some other subcommands like blueutil --is-connected "WF-1000XM3" in my script, which returns No paired or recent devices to search for: "WF-1000XM3" so obviously it can't work in this context... This makes this a different question, which I might post later or not, but I guess this specific issue is resolved. Thank you all for your help! ...Unless anyone knows another reason?


first line is a error: "#!/usr/bin/env bash"
export PATH is a error: export PATH="/Users/klumpy/Library/Scripts:$PATH"
If follow a string echo $(blueutil --connected) return is null, then used res=$(blueutil --connected); echo $res or used full path (for example /usr/bin/blueutil).

